# python regex to separate list substrings in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this `'[[20, 20.4,aa], [c, 10.5, eee]]'`.
My aim is to enclose the characters inside single quotes and leave the numbers as it is.

For example:

```
examples:
s1 = "[[20, 20.4, aa], [c, 10.5, eee]]"
s2 = "[[a , bg, 20], [cff, 20, edd]]"

required:
s1 = "[[20, 20.4,'aa'], ['c', 10.5, 'eee']]"
s2 = "[[a , 'bg', 20], ['cff', 20, 'edd']]"
```

I have done so far this:

```
s = '[[20, 20.4,a], [c, 10.5, e]]'

s = ''.join(["'"+ i + "'" if i.isalpha() else i for i in s])
s # "[[20, 20.4,'a'], ['c', 10.5, 'e']]"
```

But it works only for single characters. If I have `aa` it will give `'a''a'` which is wrong.
How the problem can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

s1 = '[[20, 20.4,aa], [c, 10.5, eee]]'
s2 = '[[a , bg,20], [cff, 20, edd]]'

rs1 = re.sub('([a-zA-Z]+)', r"'\1'", s1)
print(rs1)
rs2 = re.sub('([a-zA-Z]+)', r"'\1'", s2)
print(rs2)
```

**Output**

```
[[20, 20.4,'aa'], ['c', 10.5, 'eee']]
[['a' , 'bg',20], ['cff', 20, 'edd']]
```

The pattern `([a-zA-Z]+)` means match one or more letters and put them inside a group, then refer to that group `r"'\1'"` and surrounded with single quotes.

Comment: follow up: how to do the same for `s = '10.5   [c, 10.5, eee]]'` to get `mylist = [10.5, ['c', 10.5, 'eee']]` ?